# Read CSV file in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I'm trying to read CSV file.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\San\TEMP OLSTP MECH AMT.csv')
df.head()
```

But when I show the dataset, it looks messed up.
[image]

contd.
[image]

**How to fix it? Is there any set up needed?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data is `;`-sheared, you need to inform `pandas` about that, try

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\San\TEMP OLSTP MECH AMT.csv',sep=";")
df.head()
```

Read [`pandas.read_csv` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) if you want to know more

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  import pandas as pd
 df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\San\TEMP OLSTP MECH 
           AMT.csv', sep=';' ) 
  df.head()
```